# .htaccess redirect root to subfolder without showing the subfolder in URL

Tags: git, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect my root to a subfolder but without showing this in the URL.

I'm working with git and, therefore I have my project in the git folder on the root. With .htacccess I'm trying to let the subfolder act as the root, the following situation.

1. enter in browser: [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)
2. results in browser: [www.domain.com/git-repo-folder/](http://www.domain.com/git-repo-folder/)
3. but I don't want the /git-repo-folder/ to show.
4. same goes for: [www.domain.com/git-repo-folder/interesting-page.html](http://www.domain.com/git-repo-folder/interesting-page.html)
5. should be: [www.domain.com/interesting-page.html](http://www.domain.com/interesting-page.html) in the browser

What I have now is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch ^/$ /git-repo-folder/
```

Comment: Your `git-repo-folder` — is it a directory with static files? Or there is a CGI script that serves the repository? For static files you don't need redirect, you just change your `DocumentRoot` to point to `git-repo-folder`.

Comment: @phd Hello my newest best friend :) again you've helped me. Thank you so much for that. There is no CGI script running, so change of DocumentRoot will do the trick. I was stuck thinking in the .htaccess. If you like you can change the comment into an answer and I will give you the credits for it. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/git-repo-folder
```

should be enough. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot